# Grub repaired after W10 update, but now W10 won't boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have W10/Ubuntu 18 dual boot, both systems on one SSD (booting BIOS, not UEFI)
Recent W10 update messed up my partitions and I got grub rescue screen. I was able to fix it with recovering linux partition using parted rescue. After that I was able to boot, selected W10 and it successfully finished the update process. After that I was able to boot int Ubuntu, but with a slight issue - "No symbol table"

I run

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
sudo update-grub
```

It fixed the linux boot, but now when I select my W10 from grub menu
it just reboots and back to the grub menu.

Here is my disk partitions:

```
~$ sudo parted /dev/sda print
Model: ATA Samsung SSD 850 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 256GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  106MB  105MB   primary   ntfs
 2      106MB   144GB  144GB   primary   ntfs            boot
 3      144GB   144GB  543MB   primary   ntfs            diag
 4      144GB   256GB  112GB   extended
 6      144GB   248GB  104GB   logical   ext4
 5      248GB   256GB  8210MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
```

My W10 is number 3, which I confirm by `ls (hd0,msdos2)/` in grub

What I see in the grub.cfg for W10 section:

```
menuentry 'Windows 10 (on /dev/sda1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-68349BA7349B7732' {
        savedefault
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ntfs
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  68349BA7349B7732
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 68349BA7349B7732
        fi
        parttool ${root} hidden-
        drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
        chainloader +1
}
```

That seems to be wrong as it points to hd0,msdos1 the small reserved  partition, the UUID of W10 partition is 86CA9C8FCA9C7CDD and it is hd0,msdos2 (/dev/sda2)

I tried to re-run os-prober and update-grub, but nothing changes.
Please help me to recover my W10 booting from grub menu, thanks in advance.

Comment: Windows in BIOS boot mode normally has a small Boot partition that is the correct partition for grub to boot. But grub only boots working Windows. If Windows needs chkdsk or is hibernated (and that includes fast start up) then grub will not boot it. You then have to temporarily install a Windows boot loader, fix Windows & then restore grub. If still issues post link to Summary report from Boot-Repair.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Make a copy of grub.cfg. Then open it with `sudo gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg`. Go to the Windows 10 `menuentry` and change all entries of *msdos1*  to *msdos2*. Also check that the correct UUID for sda2 is shown as well. Then save and reboot.

Comment: Paul Benson - I actually tried that, but it resulted in BOOTMGR missing message, so I reverted the grub.cgf back to original

Comment: oldfred - here is the info page collected with boot-repair:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/KgFN3Vs5F6/

Comment: That's nothing to do with grub or Ubuntu. If you try to boot into Windows independently from BIOS boot (you need to know the right 'F' key for your machine) it should show both systems. I expect that if you then try to boot Windows from there you will get the same message. It means your BCD file is corrupted or missing.

Comment: Paul Benson - I doubt it, because as I said, after linux partition was restored I was able to boot W10 and it finished the update and I was able to re-boot into W10 again. I left W10 in a perfect state, I finished my last Windows session with restart (not shutdown) to ensure W10 does actually flush all buffers and don't do any hibernate tricks.

Comment: Paul Benson - just to clarify:
It got broken when I attempted to fix "no symbol table" during Linux boot, see my initial post please.
In fact I did try F12 and F2 (this is Dell XPS) and tried to play with boot sequence, but I always see grub boot, never the original OS boot, I guess this is because system is in BIOS mode.

Comment: If you're getting 'boot manager is missing' error then you have an issue with your Windows boot files. Whatever the cause is Ubuntu will not fix it. As I mentioned below, you need either a W10 installation USB, or borrow a W0 computer and make a 'W7' repair disk on a blank CD and boot from that. Both methods will lead you to  [W10 Advanced Startup](https://www.howtogeek.com/131916/how-to-use-the-advanced-startup-options-to-fix-your-windows-8-computer/) options from where you can fix W10 boot-up.

Comment: No I do not get boot mgr missing
I don't have any media to burn W10 disk, as the size is > 5GB, as soon as I will get a flash drive or DL DVD I will try and report here

Answer (score 0):

Boot repair states:

```
=================== Suggested repair

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub2 of
sda6 into the MBR of sda. 

Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s fix-windows-boot
```

Select the **Recommended Repair** option to fix Windows boot:

[image: boot repair]

Comment: I followed through with boot-repair - recommended option, but it did not help. Now I have two W10 entries in the grub menu, one points to /dev/sda1 and second to /dev/sda2 and both result in just system rebooting right back into grub. So, that did not help.

Comment: My new info from boot-repair is here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/sMJSMsxGW3/

Comment: @michaelubu You can try boot-repair a second time. It's possible it finds new things to fix now.

Comment: Retried, but nothing changed, still the same two W10 items on the grub menu, both result in reboot.

Comment: Boot-repair will not fix a Windows boot problem where there is a fault with a Windows boot file, which is what you have. You can repair this from Windows if you made a USB drive for a W10  installation, which has a repair feature as well.

Comment: @PaulBenson makes a very good point. Here is an article that can help you repair Windows 10: https://www.groovypost.com/howto/fix-windows-10-wont-boot-startup-repair-bootrec/

Comment: I spent many hours over the weekend trying to repair W10 fighting with various problems, the bootrec /fixboot being one of many others... Ended up with digging up old harddrive with my old system image which I restored, overwriting everything, then installing all the windows updates, including 1903 (which killed my system in the first place). When W10 was settled, I just installed the Ubuntu and restored my dev environment. that I managed to backup before W10 overwrite. So, lesson learnt here - can't go easy on your backups